# PostgreSQL: find minimum value across multiple columns but return column name

Tags: arrays, postgresql, case

For each row in a table, I want to find the minimum value across a couple of numeric columns, then take the **name** of that column (which holds the desired value) and populate a **new** column with the name (or custom string).

A few rules first in my specific scenario: the value to be found across the columns must also be > 0. Also, if no value in the column is > 0, then a custom string should be placed (ie. 'none').

For example, take this table below with columns `alpha` to `delta` storing the values:

```
  id  | alpha  | bravo  | charlie | delta  
------+--------+--------+---------+--------
    1 |   5    |   2.3  |  -1     |  -5    
    2 |   9    |   8    |   3     |   1    
    3 |  -1    |  -4    |  -7     |  -9
    4 |   6.1  |   4    |   3.9   |   0
```

for each row, I want to find out which column holds the lowest positive value. My expected output is something like this:

```
  id  | alpha  | bravo  | charlie | delta  | lowest_postive
------+--------+--------+---------+--------+---------------
    1 |   5    |   2.3  |  -1     |  -5    |  'col: bravo'
    2 |   9    |   8    |   3     |   1    |  'col: delta'
    3 |  -1    |  -4    |  -7     |  -9    |  'col: none'
    4 |   6.1  |   4    |   3.9   |   0    |  'col: charlie'
```

Should I use a `CASE ... WHEN ... THEN ...`? Should I be converting the row into an array first, then assinging each position in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
select *,
  case when mp = alpha then 'col: alpha'
       when mp = bravo then 'col: bravo'
       when mp = charlie then 'col: charlie'
       when mp = delta then 'col: delta'
  end as lower_positive
from (
  select *,
    least(
      case when alpha > 0 then alpha end,
      case when bravo > 0 then bravo end,
      case when charlie > 0 then charlie end,
      case when delta > 0 then delta end
    ) as mp
  from t
) x
```

However, this solution doesn't account for multiple minimums; the first one (from left ro right) wins.

Comment: This works well. It just needs an `else 'col: none'` after line 5 as a catch.

Comment: This works great when dealing with a handful of columns. But say there were 100 columns and you didn't want to write out `case .. when ... then` 100 times... how'd you go about that? This time, assume that custom strings aren't required in the new output column.

Comment: @TheoF If the table has 100 **separate** columns, this solution or a similar one is the way to go. Now, if you had a **single** column of type array, then that could be processed with a different query.

Comment: you say the first one from left to right wins, but how could you make it so the furthest right wins?

Comment: @TheoF To make it so the first one (from right to left) wins, change line 2-5 and place the `WHEN ...` clauses in the opposite order.